# PySide2 QUiLoader returns an empty window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside2

PySide2(5.6.0~a1) Qt UI file loader returns an empty window whereare PyQt5 loader works fine. Could you explained to me where I am wrong.

Non Working PySide2 version:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PySide2 import QtUiTools

class AppWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load("dialog1.ui")
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = AppWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Working PyQt5 version:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic

class AppWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = uic.loadUi("dialog1.ui", self)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = AppWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Using this function also does not work :

```
def loadUiWidget(uifilename, parent=None):
    loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
    uifile = QtCore.QFile(uifilename)
    uifile.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
    ui = loader.load(uifile, parent)
    uifile.close()
    return ui
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`QUiLoader().load()` returns the widget as an object so if you assign it to a variable it will not do anything, you should use `show()`:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PySide2 import QtUiTools

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load("dialog1.ui")
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks Eyllanesc. In my case, I made the following change : self.ui.show()

Comment: .... It works but I lost the signal/slot configuration I made in Qt Designer, which is not a big deal.
Do you know a way to achieve the same result as in PyQt5, that is, all widgets created in Qt Designer are instance variables of class Mydialog?

Comment: @u2gilles were you able to find an answer to this? I'm facing the same thing... thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In PySide2 there's no function to QMainWindow class overwrite itself. It's necessary to show the ui:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PySide2 import QtUiTools

class AppWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = QtUiTools.QUiLoader().load("dialog1.ui")
        self.ui.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = AppWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is just wrong. Besides the fact that it's unclear what that QMainWindow reference should mean, that `AppWindow` class and its instance become almost useless if used like that, since the only window actually shown and used is the `self.ui` member. That's ***not*** how QUiLoader is supposed to be used.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to load `QMainWindow` from designer `*.ui` file you can use

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setCentralWidget(QUiLoader().load("form.ui"))
```

**but slot-signal bindings, which are set in the designer in `*.ui` file, are not working anyway**.

So, for full-function use of designer GUI and slot-signal bindings, the only way I found is to compile *.ui file to python module with pyside UI compiler:

```sh
pyside2-uic mainwindow.ui > ui_mainwindow.py
```

and then include produced `ui_mainwindow`. In this method the slot-signal pairs from Qt UI designer will work well.

```py
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
```